# Input text taking extra space in input field

Tags: javascript, html

I'm sending a button text into an input field. But in the input field button, the text is taking extra space from left sight and input is not taking the text as a value. When I remove the extra space with keyboard backspace then it's taking the text as value. Here is my code and screenshot:

[image]

```
<form action="add_content_system.php" method="POST">
<div class="form-group form-text">
    <div class="form-label-group">
        <input name="name" type="text" id="destination_two" class="form- 
        control" placeholder="Name" required="required" autofocus value="">
        <label for="destination_two">Name</label>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.sourcelink').click(function() {
    $('#destination_two').val($(this).html()); 
    }); 
 });
</script>
```

Comment: where is the `.sourcelink` element in the HTML ?

Comment: Please update your question with a JSFiddle.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't get your question exactly. . Did u want like this?

```js
function myFunction() {
  var Name = document.getElementById("inputName").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Your Name is: " + Name;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <label for="name">Insert Your Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="inputName" class="form-control" placeholder="name" required autofocus value="" oninput="myFunction();">
  <p id="demo">Your Name is: </p>
</form>
```